# filter rows to keep only until last occurence of a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe after groupby based on an id.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2022/01/01', '2022/01/02', '2022/01/03', '2022/01/04', '2022/01/05', '2022/01/06', '2022/01/07', '2022/01/08', '2022/01/09', '2022/01/10', '2022/01/11', '2022/01/12', '2022/01/13', '2022/01/14', '2022/01/15', '2022/01/16', '2022/01/17', '2022/01/18', '2022/01/19', '2022/01/20', '2022/01/21', '2022/01/22', '2022/01/23', '2022/01/24', '2022/01/25', '2022/01/26', '2022/01/27', '2022/01/28', '2022/01/29', '2022/01/30', '2022/01/31'],
                   'value': [1, 3, 5, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]})
```

in the above dataframe, after 2022/01/06 values are zero. so I want to identify such date after which values remain zero and drop them.
expected output dataframe is

```
>>> df
         date  value
 0  2022/01/01  1
 1  2022/01/02  3
 2  2022/01/03  5
 3  2022/01/04  0
 4  2022/01/05  0
 5  2022/01/06  2
```

so in the example, I should be able to identify that 2022/01/06 is cancel date as after which values for all dates are 0s.

Comment: and your question is...? Where did exactly your attempts fail at?

Comment: @Neither can not think of a way to identify such a date in a neat way and drop based on that, don't want to apply for loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cumulative sum in inverted Series by [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html) with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and compare for not equal `0` - so it remove all last `0` values per column `value` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['value'].iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1].ne(0)]
print (df)
         date  value
0  2022/01/01      1
1  2022/01/02      3
2  2022/01/03      5
3  2022/01/04      0
4  2022/01/05      0
5  2022/01/06      2
```

With drop is it possible:

```
df.drop(df[df['value'].iloc[::-1].cumsum().eq(0).iloc[::-1]].index)
```

EDIT: Solution per groups with [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
df = df[df.iloc[::-1].groupby('ID')['value'].cumsum().iloc[::-1].ne(0)]
```

Comment: df.drop(df[(df['value'].iloc[::-1].cumsum().ne(0).iloc[::-1] == False)].index); I changed it a little bit for my use case. This I want to appy after groupby on dataframe so that for each group it happens. can you suggest ? df.groupby('ID').drop(...)

Comment: @007 - Why is necessary `drop` ? Added solution with `groupby`

Comment: I have to add one more condition in the groupby clause. Asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70678001/filter-rows-of-pandas-dataframe-based-on-groupby-multiple-conditions

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking of this solution now, using [`last_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.last_valid_index.html) on the masked column:

```
df.loc[:df['value'].mask(df['value'].eq(0)).last_valid_index()]
```

output:

```
         date  value
0  2022/01/01      1
1  2022/01/02      3
2  2022/01/03      5
3  2022/01/04      0
4  2022/01/05      0
5  2022/01/06      2
```