# filter rows of pandas dataframe based on groupby multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[123,date(year=2021,month=12,day=1),1,date(year=2021,month=12,day=6)],[123,date(year=2021,month=12,day=2),3,date(year=2021,month=12,day=6)],[123,date(year=2021,month=12,day=3),5,date(year=2021,month=12,day=6)],[123,date(year=2021,month=12,day=4),0,date(year=2021,month=12,day=6)],[123,date(year=2021,month=12,day=5),0,date(year=2021,month=12,day=6)],[123,date(year=2021,month=12,day=6),0,date(year=2021,month=12,day=6)],[123,date(year=2021,month=12,day=7),0,date(year=2021,month=12,day=6)],[123,date(year=2021,month=12,day=8),0,date(year=2021,month=12,day=6)],[123,date(year=2021,month=12,day=9),0,date(year=2021,month=12,day=6)],[123,date(year=2021,month=12,day=10),0,date(year=2021,month=12,day=6)],[456,date(year=2021,month=12,day=1),1,date(year=2021,month=12,day=11)],[456,date(year=2021,month=12,day=2),3,date(year=2021,month=12,day=11)],[456,date(year=2021,month=12,day=3),5,date(year=2021,month=12,day=11)],[456,date(year=2021,month=12,day=4),0,date(year=2021,month=12,day=11)],[456,date(year=2021,month=12,day=5),0,date(year=2021,month=12,day=11)],[456,date(year=2021,month=12,day=6),2,date(year=2021,month=12,day=11)],[456,date(year=2021,month=12,day=7),3,date(year=2021,month=12,day=11)],[456,date(year=2021,month=12,day=8),0,date(year=2021,month=12,day=11)],[456,date(year=2021,month=12,day=9),0,date(year=2021,month=12,day=11)],[456,date(year=2021,month=12,day=10),0,date(year=2021,month=12,day=11)]], columns=['ID','date', 'value','Matdate'])
```

Looking like:

```
     ID        date  value     Matdate
0   123  2021-12-01      1  2021-12-06
1   123  2021-12-02      3  2021-12-06
2   123  2021-12-03      5  2021-12-06
3   123  2021-12-04      0  2021-12-06
4   123  2021-12-05      0  2021-12-06
5   123  2021-12-06      0  2021-12-06
6   123  2021-12-07      0  2021-12-06
7   123  2021-12-08      0  2021-12-06
8   123  2021-12-09      0  2021-12-06
9   123  2021-12-10      0  2021-12-06
10  456  2021-12-01      1  2021-12-11
11  456  2021-12-02      3  2021-12-11
12  456  2021-12-03      5  2021-12-11
13  456  2021-12-04      0  2021-12-11
14  456  2021-12-05      0  2021-12-11
15  456  2021-12-06      2  2021-12-11
16  456  2021-12-07      3  2021-12-11
17  456  2021-12-08      0  2021-12-11
18  456  2021-12-09      0  2021-12-11
19  456  2021-12-10      0  2021-12-11
```

The desired dataframe is:

```
     ID        date  value     Matdate
0   123  2021-12-01      1  2021-12-06
1   123  2021-12-02      3  2021-12-06
2   123  2021-12-03      5  2021-12-06
3   123  2021-12-04      0  2021-12-06
4   123  2021-12-05      0  2021-12-06
5   123  2021-12-06      0  2021-12-06
10  456  2021-12-01      1  2021-12-11
11  456  2021-12-02      3  2021-12-11
12  456  2021-12-03      5  2021-12-11
13  456  2021-12-04      0  2021-12-11
14  456  2021-12-05      0  2021-12-11
15  456  2021-12-06      2  2021-12-11
16  456  2021-12-07      3  2021-12-11
```

Basically I have to drop rows based on two conditions in group by ID.

> if the value column contains just 0 values till last date and those row for which date is greater than Matdate. if Matdate is less than equal to date then don't drop it.
> I have tried something like the following so far.

```
df.drop( df[(df.iloc[::-1].groupby('ID')['value'].cumsum().iloc[::-1].ne(0) == False) & df.groupby('ID')['date'] > df.groupby('ID')['Matdate'] ].index )
```

Comment: why are rows 17-19 dropped?

Comment: because for 456 ID, it has trailing zeros, the first condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare values without groups, so your solution is changed with remove `groupby`:

```
df['Matdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Matdate'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

m1 = (df.iloc[::-1].groupby('ID')['value'].cumsum().iloc[::-1].eq(0))
m2 = (df['date'] > df['Matdate'])
m3 = (df['Matdate'].dt.weekday != 0)


df1 = df[(m1 & m2) | (m1 & m3)] 
print (df1)
     ID       date  value    Matdate
6   123 2021-12-07      0 2021-12-06
7   123 2021-12-08      0 2021-12-06
8   123 2021-12-09      0 2021-12-06
9   123 2021-12-10      0 2021-12-06
17  456 2021-12-08      0 2021-12-11
18  456 2021-12-09      0 2021-12-11
19  456 2021-12-10      0 2021-12-11

df.drop(df1.index)
```

Comment: by this rows 17,18,19 are not getting dropped ...

Comment: @007 - because `if Matdate is less than equal to date then don't drop it`

Comment: umm Matdate is 2021-12-11 and dates are 2021-12-08, 2021-12-09, 2021-12-10, so Matdate is greater than date, so they should be dropped.

Comment: let me better it, 2021-12-06 is a monday, so when Matdate is Monday don't drop based on cumsum 0 (i.e trailing zeros) condition, when its not a Monday then drop if trailing zeros are there. something like df1 = df[(df.iloc[::-1].groupby('ID')['value'].cumsum().iloc[::-1].eq(0)) & ( df['Matdate'].weekday() != 0) ] and df.drop(df1.index)

Comment: @007 - Can you test now?